# Visual MySQL Workbench Error: 1452 foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, relationships

Been looking at this for two days and am at a loss as to what this means. I know it means "exactly what it says" but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone explain it to me in layman's terms and help me out?

```
ERROR: Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`sls11n`.`dependent`, CONSTRAINT `fk_dependent_employee1` FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
 REFERENCES `employee` (`emp_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)



INSERT INTO `sls11n`.`dependent` (`dep_id`, `emp_id`, `dep_ssn`, `dep_fname`, `dep_lname`,
 `dep_street`, `dep_city`, `dep_state`, `dep_zip`, `dep_phone`, `dep_email`, `dep_notes`)
 VALUES (NULL, 13, 123456789, 'Gary', 'Hart', 'West St', 'San Diego', 'CA', '23424', 
'1234567890', 'garyhart@me.com', NULL)
```

Here's the script that I believe is relevant:

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sls11n`.`employee`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sls11n`.`employee` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sls11n`.`employee` (
  `emp_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_ssn` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `emp_fname` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `emp_lname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `emp_street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `emp_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `emp_zip` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  `emp_phone` CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `emp_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `emp_doh` DATE NOT NULL,
  `emp_is_inspect` ENUM('y', 'n') NOT NULL,
  `emp_notes` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SHOW WARNINGS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `sls11n`.`dependent`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `sls11n`.`dependent` ;

SHOW WARNINGS;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sls11n`.`dependent` (
  `dep_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dep_ssn` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `dep_fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dep_lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dep_street` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dep_city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dep_state` CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  `dep_zip` CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  `dep_phone` CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `dep_email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `dep_notes` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dep_id`),
  INDEX `fk_dependent_employee1_idx` (`emp_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dependent_employee1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`emp_id`)
    REFERENCES `sls11n`.`employee` (`emp_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Any one have any ideas? Please use simple terms, I'm not kidding when I say I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The foreign key constraint says that each dependent's `emp_id` must match an existing `emp_id` in the `employee` table. So before you add this row to the `dependent` table, you have to add a row to `employee` with `emp_id = 13`.